# Conditional build trigger

Tags: teamcity

I have a situation I'd like to know if possible. I have two separate projects:

- Project A: I'd like this project to only be kicked off if files are changed in a certain folder
- Project B: Needs project A to be built first but if it doesn't get kicked off, I'd like for it to still run a build.

Is this a possibility in Team City? I am using the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

You can set up one configuration to build Project A (call this Configuration A).
Then set up Configuration B which builds Project B.  It can have artifact + snapshot dependency on Configuration A and also a Finish Build trigger so that it runs whenever Configuration A has finished.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/artifact-dependencies.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-finish-build-trigger.html

Whether this complexity is worth it probably depends on how long it takes to build Project A.